# Is it possible to change a query's parallelism while running on Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I am running a query from TOAD on Oracle 11gR2 database. While the query is running, (it takes from 60 to 400 seconds depending on the parallelism), I check its status from Session Browser of TOAD, and I realized that degree of parallelism can be change during execution, when I first look in the Session Browser it seems like query has a 16 parallelism degree, when I refresh the screen it may become 8, or 2, or 1. Or it may increase to 32.

Is there a mechanism to change a query's degree of parallelism while running on Oracle, or is TOAD malfunctioning while showing parallelism degrees of sessions?

Comment: By the way I have TOAD version 11.6.0.43.

Answer (score 2):

A specific Degree of Parallelism(DOP) can be requested from Oracle Database. For example, you can set a fixed DOP at a table or index level:

For eg:

```
ALTER TABLES sales PARALLEL 8;
ALTER TABLE customers PARALLEL 4;
```

In this case, queries accessing just the sales table use a requested DOP of 8 and queries accessing the customers table request a DOP of 4. A query accessing both the sales and the customers tables is processed with a DOP of 8 and potentially allocates 16 parallel servers (producer or consumer); whenever different DOPs are specified, Oracle Database uses the higher DOP.

If the PARALLEL clause is specified but no degree of parallelism is listed, the object gets the default DOP. Default parallelism uses a formula to determine the DOP based on the system configuration, as in the following:

For a single instance,

> DOP = PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU x CPU_COUNT

For an Oracle RAC configuration,

> DOP = PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU x CPU_COUNT x INSTANCE_COUNT

By default, `INSTANCE_COUNT` is all of the nodes in the cluster. However, if you have used Oracle RAC services to limit the number of nodes across which a parallel operation can execute, then the number of participating nodes is the number of nodes belonging to that service. For example, on a 4-node Oracle RAC cluster, with each node having 8 CPU cores and no Oracle RAC services, the `default DOP would be 2 x 8 x 4 = 64`.

The default DOP algorithm is **designed to use maximum resources and assumes that the operation finishes faster if it can use more resources. Default parallelism targets the single-user workload**. In a multiuser environment, default parallelism is not recommended.

The optimizer automatically determines the DOP for a statement based on the resource requirements of the statement. The optimizer uses the cost of all scan operations (full table scan, index fast full scan, and so on) in the execution plan to determine the necessary DOP for the statement.

However, the optimizer limits the actual DOP to ensure parallel server processes do not overwhelm the system. This limit is set by the parameter `PARALLEL_DEGREE_LIMIT.`

I've listed the important bits here for brevity.

All of this and more at the official Oracle docs -

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm#BEICCFIE

This is a very interesting setting and I suggest you go through the whole thing since its pretty helpful

Answer (score 2):

What I think you're seeing here is varying degrees of parallelism because different operations within a query will each have their own degree. Scanning different tables will involve different degrees, and a merge based on the result set of a join can have a different degree to the join itself.

One issue often forgotten is that the number of PQ slaves is often double the degree of parallelism of a query, because reading the table is carried out at the table's D.o.P. but another set of slaves might be required in order to consume the rows (for an aggregation, for example).